# Button to Add a record & subsequently view/edit that record specifically

Tags: ms-access, vba, subform

Could you please help me regarding this coding issue.

I have 3 forms as follows:

1) frmAuditProceduresMain – A main form which includes data that will be used later.

2) frmAuditProceduresSummarySubFrom – which is the subform of frmAuditProceduresMain mentioned above. This form includes the button which triggers the code.

3) frmAuditProceduresDetails – A separate standalone form that opens on pressing the button in frmAuditProceduresSummarySubFrom.

Both frmAuditProceduresSummarySubFrom and frmAuditProceduresDetails includes a field called ProcedureName.

Initially I open frmAuditProceduresMain & through it I right the data in the ProcedureName field of its subform (whose name is frmAuditProceduresSummarySubFrom) then I press the button that is located next to this record.

When the button is pressed frmAuditProceduresDetails should open and as it is the first time to add that record, the ProcedureName that I have just added should be added automatically in the ProcedureName field of frmAuditProceduresDetails along with another field from frmAuditProceduresSummarySubFrom called ProcedureID in addition to getting data from fields of the main form (frmAuditProceduresMain).

But if the records already exist, I need when I press the button, I can view/edit that record specifically on the frmAuditProceduresDetails.

I wrote the following code, but it returns all the field of frmAuditProceduresDetails as empty and I do not know why:

```
Public Sub cmdAuditProceduresDetails_Click()

DoCmd.Save
Form.Refresh

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAuditProceduresDetails", acNormal, , , acFormAdd, acWindowNormal

If Forms!frmAuditProceduresDetails!ProcedureName <> Me.ProcedureName Then

Forms!frmAuditProceduresDetails!ProcedureName = Me.ProcedureName
Forms!frmAuditProceduresDetails!ProcedureID = Me.ProcedureID

Forms!frmAuditProceduresDetails!AuCode = Me.Parent!AuCode
Forms!frmAuditProceduresDetails!AuName = Me.Parent!AuName
Forms!frmAuditProceduresDetails!AuditCycle = Me.Parent!AuditCycle

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRefresh

Else

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAuditProceduresDetails", , , "ProcedureName = '" & Nz(Me.ProcedureName, "") & "'"

End If

End Sub
```

I shall be grateful if anyone can help me regarding it.

Regards.

Raya.

Comment: What are you trying to Refresh with `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRefresh`

Comment: @dbmitch it is to ensure that the form has been filled with data obtained from other forms like ProcedureName, AuCode, AuName.